# two conditions in if statement with php

Tags: php

is that possible to do that?

```
<?php if($limit != "0" && $num_down < $limit || $limit == "0") {

//stuff

}
?>
```

i need to check if limit equals to 0 or if it is not, if $num_down is under limit.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if( ($limit != 0 && $num_down < $limit) || $limit == 0 )
{
  whateves();
}
```

You can do it this way if you want to evaluate the first condition before the second. You can also use another if branch.

Check out [the manual page for operator precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Answer (score 4):

Don't make it any more complicated than necessary:

```
if ($limit == 0 || $num_down < $limit) {
    ...
}
```

This works because the [logical or](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) (`||`) evaluates to true if *either or both* of its arguments evaluate to true.

Answer (score 0):

Your question can be a little confusing. 
But if i try to analyse it seriously, you mean:

IF $num_down is under $limit.

THEN

You want to check if $limit is EQUAL to 0 ?

Is that right ?

If so then the code should go like this.

```
if ($num_down < $limit) {
    if ($limit == 0) {  // <----If $limit is not EQUAL to 0 it will just not enter here
        // stuff
    }   
}
```

Depending of what you really need, a " if "  into a  " if " , could be your solution